# Laravel database query creation UI

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

## Background

Suppose there is a large database that has a lot of sensitive information, and query access to the database is:

1. done by generally non-technical people
2. requires approval by upper management.

So the flow would be something like this:

1. staff use a UI to create a query request
2. this query request would be saved as a laravel Job or something like that
3. along with the request will be a reason justifying the request
4. Admin approves or denies the request on a case by case basis depending on the volume and nature of data required along with the provided justification.
5. request gets executed if approved and results appear to the requester.

## Problem/Question

I was designing step 1 above, and it looks something like this:
[image]

This seems like a hell a lot of work if done from scratch. Is there an out of the box open source library that can help do this?

Note: front end is angular 1.6 JS, But I don't mind using whatever other client side js library for that (whether it's pre-baked into laravel or any other library for that matter ie react/vue/vanilla js etc). The db is Postgresql

Comment: I feel you should start looking into ACL direction, where you can define roles (and groups) that will contain the information about which columns a particular role can read, write or manage. Depending on your current situation I believe this may even be done with Active Directory or other ACLs used in your environment. 
On the other hand it may be viable to draft a list of most used queries and allocate roles there, where the query will be designed and access to its results will be controlled by ACL.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov that level of granularity in terms of authorization simply doesn't map with the kinds of requests that are made.. it's a lot more dynamic than a 1:1 relationship between authorization and column name

Comment: You don't have to create a role for each column, a role controls which _collection_ of columns user has access to. With ACLs it can be as granular or coarse as one choose it to be, @abbood

Comment: what is an ACL again?

Comment: ACL - Access control list, or essentially a declaration of access rights - read or write, for example.

Comment: Again that's not good enough.. b/c what is allowed to be done today may not be allowed to be done tomorrow.. the point is that there _needs_ to be human intervention to approve/reject requests based on the reasons provided (i'll update the question)